# How to get the value from an Object

Tags: java, object

From the below line I get an Object of `PdsLongAttrImpl`

```
Object obj = typeInfo.getParseMethod().invoke(null, rawValue);
```

And that object has `propertyKey` and `Value` as the fields.

How can I get the Value from that particular above Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the `obj` to type of the return.

For example if your expected return type is `PdsLongAttrImpl`

Then, it would be:

```
PdsLongAttrImpl pdsObj = (PdsLongAttrImpl)obj;
```

//Then perform operation on `pdsObj`.

NOTE: If obj is not of the type you are casting to, you will end up with `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 1):

Just cast the value to the proper type:

```
 YourTypeHere obj = (YourTypeHere)typeInfo.getParseMethod().invoke(null, rawValue);
```

If you are not sure about the type, you can use:

```
 System.out.println(typeInfo.getParseMethod().invoke(null, rawValue).getClass().getName));
```

this will print the name of the class on the console

Answer (score 0):

If you know what type the object is (and that PdsAttrImpl is a visible class to your code), you can cast it like

```
PdsLongAttrImpl casted = (PdsLongAttrImpl)obj;

//assuming you have getXXX methods for the two fields

casted.getPropertyKey();
casted.getValue();
```